# How Find the diophantine equation $x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}\cdots x_{n}=x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots +x_{n}$

Tags: number-theory

> let $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}$ such 
>   $$n\ge 3,x_{1}\le x_{2}\le\cdots x_{n}$$
>   $$x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}\cdots x_{n}=x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots +x_{n}$$
>
> let the number of ordered pairs of postive integers $(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n})$ is $f(n)$

we can find the $f(n)$  closed form?  I guess we have  $$f(n)\le n？$$

it is clear 
$$1+2+3=1\cdot 2\cdot 3$$

Comment: Why do you think that $f(n)\ge n$? What other triples$(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ satisfy the conditions?

Comment: @miracle173,sorry,I guess $f(n)\le n$

Comment: There is a lot of information about this problem in Guy, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory, problem D24: Sum equals product. See also Ecker, Math Mag 75 (2002) 41-47 and Math Reviews MR 99a:11034.

Comment: Number of ordered pairs? Did you mean number of ordered $n$-tuples?

Answer (score 3):

So far, there are only very large bounds known, i.e., $f(n)\le n^n$. This follows
easily from the fact that for a solution $(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)$ the largest 
component can be at most $n$. However, there is an algorithm how o find *all* solutions to the equal-sum-product Diophantine equation, see 
[here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.3874). The algorithm should give a better bound, though still large, probably. For another discussion of the bound, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35375/bound-on-the-number-of-solutions-of-a-specific-diophantine-equation).

Answer (score 0):

Observing that, calling $\sigma_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ the $i$-th symmetric polynomial then $x_1+\dots+x_n=\sigma_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)$and $x_1x_2\cdots x_n=\sigma_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)$; then looking at the symmetric polynomials properties maybe you can get some informations on what you want.